How can I disable the "invite external user" functionality for an AD B2C tenant?
I have some users which need to access the backend (either via the azure portal, or via the new entra admin center) but they shouldn't be able to create new users.
I only gave them the "Reports Reader" and "Attribute Log Reader" roles (they also need to be able to see the signin logs & audit logs)
In the general "User settings" for my tenant, under "External collaboration settings", I set the "Guest invite settings" to "Only users assigned to specific admin roles can invite guest users".
However, when the users sign in, they can still invite & bulk invite users:

What am I doing wrong?
